# Backbone: Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified when saving model

Tags: backbone.js

I did read a lot of the questions regarding this particular message, but they don't seem to apply in my case.

I have this model:

```
app.Template = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: '',
    templateType: null,
    content: '',
    defaultOfType: false,
    createdAt: null,
    updatedAt: null
  }
});
```

This collection:

```
var Templates = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: app.Template,
  url: '/templates'
});

app.Templates = new Templates();
```

In my router:

```
this.view = new app.TemplateFormView({ model: new app.Template() });
```

And in that view:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(app.Templates, 'add', this.editTemplate);
  app.Templates.add(this.model);
  // rendering function, other stuff
},

saveMyTemplate: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = {};
  var oldData = this.model.previousAttributes();

  $(e.target).closest("form").find(":input").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    formData[el.attr("id")] = el.val();
  });

  this.model.set(formData).save();
}
```

When I try to save the model, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified
```

As you can see, the `url` is set in the collection and the model is a part of the collection. Any idea as to why the model doesn't seem to be a member of the collection?

Thanks!

Comment: Where and how are you doing the model.save()?

Comment: Certainly - I edited the method into my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [model.urlRoot](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) parameter.

> Specify a urlRoot if you're using a model outside of a collection, to enable the default url function to generate URLs based on the model id. "[urlRoot]/id"
>   Normally, you won't need to define this. Note that urlRoot may also be a function.

Also check if your references are correct to app and app.Templates.